# Does any body knows or has a greedy satisfiability(GSAT) and simulated annealing satisfabiilty(SA-SAT) java algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, greedy, simulated-annealing, satisfiability

I am looking for a GSAT and SA-SAT algorithm implemented in java. Does any body know about one?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (open source, java) implements several greedy algorithms (such as First Fit), Simulated Annealing and other optimization algorithms.